# How to use SumIf with multiplication in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list

```
AHU, Area, People Load W/m2  
AHU1, 1, 5  
AHU2, 1, 10  
AHU1, 2, 5  
AHU1, 2, 10  
AHU2, 2, 10
```

Results I want to achieve

```
AHU1 = 1*5+2*5+2*10=35
AHU2 = 1*10+2*10 = 30
```

I want to use `Sumif`

```
=SUMIF(UnitRef_Supply,"="&$A19, People Load * Area)
```

My example does not work; can anyone point me to what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what SUMPRODUCT is for:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((UnitRef_Supply=$A19) * People Load, Area)
```

[image]